# uninitialized constant Logger (NameError)

Tags: ruby, nameerror

I’m trying to define a custom logger for Logger class and getting uninitialized constant Logger.

The same code worked up to a few days ago, any idea what could make it break ?
https://github.com/sugarso/ScrapingTheApple/blob/master/JustScrape.rb#L48

```
Maxims-MacBook-Air:AppleSampleCodeWorker maximveksler$ ruby JustScrape.rb
JustScrape.rb:48:in `<main>’: uninitialized constant Logger (NameError)
```

Comment: It is on standard lib... you need to require it.. I don't know without requiring it.. previously how it was working as you said..

Comment: @Maxim Veksler seems "require 'logger'" might help you.Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Guys. Would one please post this as an answer so that I can close the issue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You probably need to `require 'logger'`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot initialize the logger class at the top of your program/class with :

```
require 'logger'
```

ex:

```
require 'logger'
logger = Logger.new('MyLog.log')
logger.debug("Program start");
logger.info("Hello Word!")
```

This will show in your *MyLog.log* file something like:

```
# Logfile created on 2017-05-11 11:03:20 -0400 by logger.rb/41756
D, [2017-05-11T11:03:20.802629 #57077] DEBUG -- : Program start
I, [2017-05-11T11:03:20.802689 #57077]  INFO -- : Hello Word!
```

More information [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html)